LAG previous year wrong when grouped
I have created a SQL query which will show the current sales and sales from previous year with the LAG window function, this per customer, product, year and month. A product is not always sold each year and I know that LAG does not care about missing years, therefore the CASE statement, based on this stackoverflow post: LAG function alternative. I need the results for the missing year in between
Now the problem is that on detailed level the previous year is correct with the LAG function but when it is grouped on year it does not match anymore (See table results below)
These are my tables:
DIM_CUSTOMER
DECLARE @DIM_CUSTOMERS TABLE([BusinessKey] INT,[Customer] NVARCHAR(255))
 
INSERT INTO @DIM_CUSTOMERS
VALUES 
(10000, 'Kevin N.V.'),
(10001, 'V.Z.W. Frederik'),
(10002, 'Klaas N.V.')
SELECT * FROM @DIM_CUSTOMERS

DIM_PRODUCTS
DECLARE @DIM_PRODUCTS TABLE([BusinessKey] INT, [Product] NVARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @DIM_PRODUCTS
VALUES
(9000, 'PH114'),
(9001, 'PH272'),
(9002, 'PH878'),
(9003, 'PH900')
SELECT * FROM @DIM_PRODUCTS

DIM_DATES
DECLARE @DIM_DATES TABLE([BusinessKey] INT, [Year] INT, [Month] INT, [YearMonth] INT, [YearMonthText] NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @DIM_DATES
VALUES
(202201, 2022, 1, 202201, '2022.01'),
(202202, 2022, 2, 202202, '2022.02'),
(202203, 2022, 3, 202203, '2022.03'),
(202204, 2022, 4, 202204, '2022.04'),
(202205, 2022, 5, 202205, '2022.05'),
(202206, 2022, 6, 202206, '2022.06'),
(202207, 2022, 7, 202207, '2022.07'),
(202208, 2022, 8, 202208, '2022.08'),
(202209, 2022, 9, 202209, '2022.09'),
(202210, 2022, 10, 202210, '2022.10'),
(202211, 2022, 11, 202211, '2022.11'),
(202212, 2022, 12, 202212, '2022.12'),
(202301, 2023, 1, 202301, '2023.01'),
(202302, 2023, 2, 202302, '2023.02'),
(202303, 2023, 3, 202303, '2023.03'),
(202304, 2023, 4, 202304, '2023.04'),
(202305, 2023, 5, 202305, '2023.05'),
(202306, 2023, 6, 202306, '2023.06'),
(202307, 2023, 7, 202307, '2023.07'),
(202308, 2023, 8, 202308, '2023.08'),
(202309, 2023, 9, 202309, '2023.09'),
(202310, 2023, 10, 202310, '2023.10'),
(202311, 2023, 11, 202311, '2023.11'),
(202312, 2023, 12, 202312, '2023.12'),
(202401, 2024, 1, 202401, '2024.01'),
(202402, 2024, 2, 202402, '2024.02'),
(202403, 2024, 3, 202403, '2024.03'),
(202404, 2024, 4, 202404, '2024.04'),
(202405, 2024, 5, 202405, '2024.05'),
(202406, 2024, 6, 202406, '2024.06'),
(202407, 2024, 7, 202407, '2024.07'),
(202408, 2024, 8, 202408, '2024.08'),
(202409, 2024, 9, 202409, '2024.09'),
(202410, 2024, 10, 202410, '2024.10'),
(202411, 2024, 11, 202411, '2024.11'),
(202412, 2024, 12, 202412, '2024.12')
SELECT * FROM @DIM_DATES

FACT_SALES
DECLARE @FACT_SALES TABLE([ID] INT, [FK_Product] INT, [FK_Customer] INT, [FK_Date] INT, [Sales] FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @FACT_SALES
VALUES
(1, 9000, 10000, 202303, 90.48),
(2, 9000, 10000, 202304, 20.40),
(3, 9002, 10000, 202305, 250.85),
(4, 9002, 10000, 202303, 100.50),
(5, 9000, 10000, 202403, 38.40),
(6, 9000, 10000, 202406, 474.50),
(7, 9001, 10000, 202403, 128.60),
(8, 9001, 10000, 202404, 144.97),
(9, 9000, 10002, 202303, 199.60),
(10, 9001, 10002, 202302, 58.97),
(11, 9001, 10002, 202402, 40.88),
(12, 9001, 10000, 202203, 14.5)
SELECT * FROM @FACT_SALES

MY_ATTEMPT
;WITH CustProdYears 
    AS(
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            d.[Year] as SaleYear, s.FK_Product, s.FK_Customer
            FROM @FACT_SALES   s     
            JOIN @DIM_DATES d on s.FK_Date = d.BusinessKey
    )
, CustomerSales 
    AS (
        SELECT cpy.FK_Customer, cpy.FK_Product, d.YearMonthText, s.[Sales], d.year, d.month
            FROM CustProdYears cpy 
            JOIN @DIM_DATES d on cpy.[SaleYear] = d.[Year]
            LEFT JOIN @FACT_SALES s 
                on s.FK_Customer = cpy.FK_Customer
                and s.FK_Product = cpy.FK_Product
                and s.FK_Date = d.BusinessKey
    )
SELECT b.Year,
        SUM(b.[Sales]) AS [Sales],
        SUM(b.[SalesLastYear]) AS [SalesLastYear]
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        LAG(a.year, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer,  a.Product, a.month ORDER BY a.year) AS [PreviousYear],
        CASE WHEN 1 = a.year - LAG(a.year, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer,  a.Product, a.month ORDER BY a.year)
            THEN LAG(a.[Sales], 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Customer,  a.Product, a.month ORDER BY a.year)
            ELSE 0 END AS [SalesLastYear]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
          Customer, Product, Year, Month
        , [Sales] = ISNULL([Sales], 0)
        FROM @DIM_CUSTOMERS c 
            LEFT JOIN CustomerSales s ON c.BusinessKey = s.FK_Customer
            LEFT JOIN @DIM_PRODUCTS p on s.FK_Product = p.BusinessKey
            WHERE Customer = 'Kevin N.V.'

    ) a
    --ORDER BY a.Customer, a.Product, a.year, a.month
) b
GROUP BY b.Year
ORDER BY b.Year

My result:



Year
Sales
SalesLastYear




2022
14,5
0


2023
462,23
0


2024
786,47
110,88



Expected result:



Year
Sales
SalesLastYear




2022
14,5
0


2023
462,23
0


2024
786,47
462,23



Is there a way to fix this issue?

You forgot the definition of @DIM_PRODUCTS.

LAG is returning the right values. if you look at the results before aggregation, it returns 20.4 and 90.48. For other products, like PH272, you only have data for 2024 and 2022, so there's no 2021 or 2023, so they correctly return 0 per your CASE expression. For PH878 there's no 2024 here, so no 2024 to get the prior values. db<>fiddle

If you want last year's aggregated value, why not LAG after you aggregate, not before?

@ThomA My mistake, I have added the DECLARE of @DIM_PRODUCTS. As you said, on detailed level it is correct and seems like a normal behaviour. As the product PH878 does not appear in 2024 the SalesLastYear will be 110.88 instead of 351,35 = 100.5 + 250.85.

@ThomA Do you have an example with 'LAG after you aggregate'?

LAG(SUM(<expression>)) OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)... It's really not a paradigm shift from LAG(<expression>) OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)

@ThomA OK, it is indeed showing the correct results, thank you!

Please use temp tables.  If you are working with a DW scenario, there is zero reason to go without stats or cardinality for your work.   +1 to what Thom A said as well.

You could potentially achieve this with a couple of CTEs instead of a Window function:
with years as
(
    select distinct [Year] from @DIM_DATES
),
sales as
(
    select 
        y.[Year], 
        sum(s.Sales) as Sales
    from years y
    left join @FACT_SALES s on y.[Year] = left(convert(varchar(8),s.FK_Date),4)
    left join @DIM_CUSTOMERS c on s.FK_Customer = c.BusinessKey
    where c.Customer = 'Kevin N.V.'
    group by y.[Year]
)

select 
    curr.[Year], 
    curr.Sales, 
    prev.Sales as SalesLastYear
from sales curr
left join sales prev on curr.[Year] - 1 = prev.[Year]
order by curr.[Year]

Results:
+------+--------+---------------+
| Year | Sales  | SalesLastYear |
+------+--------+---------------+
| 2022 |   14.5 | NULL          |
| 2023 | 462.23 | 14.5          |
| 2024 | 786.47 | 462.23        |
+------+--------+---------------+

Or, if you really want to use LAG(), then something like this:
select
    [Year],
    Sales,
    lag(Sales) over (order by [Year]) as SalesLastYear
from
(
    select distinct 
        d.[Year],
        sal.Sales
    from @DIM_DATES d
    outer apply
    (
        select sum(s.Sales) as Sales
        from @FACT_SALES s
        left join @DIM_CUSTOMERS c on s.FK_Customer = c.BusinessKey
        where d.[Year] = left(convert(varchar(8),s.FK_Date),4) 
        and c.Customer = 'Kevin N.V.'   
    ) sal
) r

gives the same result.
